# is there a way to modify the sbt version of an existing project in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am learning this [course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/progfun1/supplement/VuJFf/intellij-idea-tutorial).

I've installed sbt 1.2.8

```
$ sbt sbtVersion
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/yongjia/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/yongjia/project
[info] Updating ProjectRef(uri("file:/Users/yongjia/project/"), "yongjia-build")...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Set current project to yongjia (in build file:/Users/yongjia/)
[info] 1.2.8
```

the example from that course set sbt as 0.13.17

[image]

in this context, is there a way to modify the sbt version to 1.2.8?

Comment: You have the option to select the `sbt` version during project creation.

Comment: this is an existing project that comes from an online course assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing version in `yourproject/project/build.properties`

```
sbt.version=1.2.8
```

You might have to follow a migration guide [Migrating from sbt 0.13.x](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Migrating-from-sbt-013x.html#Migrating+from+sbt+0.13.x)